# Why the User role attribute in Spring boot app has to be indexed?

Tags: spring, mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to store Employee Pojo on Mongo db using Spring boot  and I found that it is indexed on one of the site in internet. what is the need and reason for it to be indexed?

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.IndexDirection;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;

@Document(collection = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed(unique = true, direction = IndexDirection.DESCENDING, dropDups = true)

    private String role;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the mongo documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

```
Indexes support the efficient execution of queries in MongoDB. Without indexes,
MongoDB must perform a collection scan, i.e. scan every document in a collection,
to select those documents that match the query statement. If an appropriate index
exists for a query, MongoDB can use the index to limit the number of documents it
must inspect.
```

There is no need for an Index on `role`. However - if you are querying your employee collection using `role` as criteria, it will speed up query execution.

Which fields to index depends on your use case / how you are accessing your data.